# Convert String to ParseObject

Tags: java, kotlin, parse-platform, back4app, parse-android-sdk

I am using the Parse Android SDK and I have an `objectId` as a `String` and I want to convert it to a `ParseObject` what is the best way either in Kotlin or Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ParseObject` with just the `objectId` and class name using the method shown below...

```java
ParseObject.createWithoutData("ClassName", "objectId")
```

You will need to use the `fetchIfNeededInBackground()` function to fetch the data for the `ParseObject` if you require it.